# Why must Windows Services be Installed?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, service

As far as I understand, the main entry point for a service application calls [StartServiceCtrlDispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686324(v=vs.85).aspx) with an array of entries containing (among other things) the entry points for services to be run.

Nothing about that setup specifically requires any kind of installation: So why must a windows service be installed anyway?

I'm assuming it's an access management/security thing, but I can't find anything on the net.

Comment: If you were to ask Windows to start a service, and the service hasn't been installed, how would Windows know what executable to use?

Comment: A service is started by the OS.  It needs to know stuff to do that right, that requires keys in the registry.  There isn't much to it, even sc.exe can do it.  Type sc.exe create /? for basic info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are not connected to a specific user and a major selling point of a service is the ability to run when there are no users logged in. If there is no user around to start a service, how would Windows know what to start if there was no central list it could consult?

The list of services is stored in the registry and this is where the service manager gets the list of installed services and their configuration.

Most 3rd-party services only contain one service per .exe and the array passed to `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` only contains one service. The famous svchost.exe can have more than one service in a single process and in this design each service is implemented in a .dll that is loaded by svchost.exe.

The svchost.exe design is used by Microsoft to reduce the total number of processes on a system. There will still be multiple svchost processes on a system, one for each configuration type (network access vs local only etc.).

Other configuration details the service manger needs to know about each service includes what action it should take if a service dies and if it should be delay-started etc. These settings are not hardcoded in the service itself so that administrators can change the configuration.